# How does the Dependency Property system know to which object instance a pirticular dependency property value belongs to

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I am a newbie to WPF, taking a look at [this](http://www.codemag.com/article/1405061) article. I am sure I am asking a very basic question, but not able to find the answer. Just at-least a nudge in the right direction would be deeply appreciated. 
I created a wpf app, then derived a [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) class as follows and defined a dependency object on it.

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    public string SecurityId
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(SecurityIdProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SecurityIdProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        SecurityIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SecurityId",
        typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxEx),
        new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

In the window constructor I see this.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TextBoxEx t1 = new TextBoxEx();
    t1.SecurityId = "abc";

    TextBoxEx t2 = new TextBoxEx();
    var secId = t2.SecurityId;

}
```

I see that secId assigned from t2.SecurityId is "", while I expect that to be "abc".

So how does the WPF dependency property system, know to which object instance a dependency property value belongs to? I see nowhere the `this` parameter is passed to the dp property system, so how does it know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SecurityId` is an instance (i.e. non-static) property, which calls the instance methods `DependencyObject.GetValue()` and `DependencyObject.SetValue()`.

If you want to see the `this` keyword somewhere, you could write the property like this:

```
public string SecurityId
{
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(SecurityIdProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(SecurityIdProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: I think I am now getting what you are saying. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the magic is in the implementation of GetValue, and it's a bit complicated: http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/07/internals-of-dependency-property-in-wpf.html